# mvn deploy with username password without configuring settings.xml

Tags: maven

Is it possible to pass the usename password in the parametres of mvn deploy :

I want to do something like :

```
mvn deploy -username USERNAME -psw PASSWORD
```

Actually the username password are picked from the server tag on the settings.xml ...

Comment: And what is the problem with picking up the things from `settings.xml` (where it belongs)..?

Comment: I'mm executing a job that doing a deploy from Jenkins, I have no control on the settings.xml ...

Comment: The correct way to handle that is to put credentials into the credentials store in Jenkins and let inject the correct things into the `setting.xml` on the Jenkins server..during the build...

Comment: If the username/password is currently stored in the settings.xml on the servers home directory this is a security issue...

Comment: YES, that s true ! but they havent configured a placeholder for that  !!!! so I cant inject my credentials ...

Comment: Than you should change that...and placeholder in the `settings.xml` on the server is wrong...The config-file-provider plugin of Jenkins handles that perfectly.

Comment: I'm working with curl actually and I pass the username/password - but I prefer using mvn deploy since it transfer all the needed things (pom.xml the correct folder ect)

Comment: Working with curl? Really? sorry to say that it in the harsh way. Simply wrong. You should check how to configure Jenkins correctly and handle it there...Are you using a repository manager to collect the built artifacts from Jenkins? If not than you should start to do so...

Comment: This is why I dont want to do so ... it is me that doing the things out of their directive ... They offers Templates to use and I wont use them ... I m building my proper Pipeline ....

Comment: The issue seemed to be that the CI solution is wrongly configured which needs to be solved to make things working well....

Comment: Ok thanks @khmarbaise ..
I dont think any way mvn deploy offer to override the username psw of the settings.xml ..

Comment: If the standard `settings.xml` does not fit your needs and you cannot change it, why not put your own `settings.xml` into your project? Then you can use it by `mvn clean deploy -s my-settings.xml`.

Comment: hmm, good idea .. but there is other resources with encrypted data .. so I can only copy paste teh content from the original settings.xml ... but I will try something yes!